# Hadoop: Specify max size/capacity for HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running a single node Hadoop deployment.  I know how much data I will require for my applications, can I set (and re-set) the *max* capacity used by HDFS?

I've tried the following, but can't seem to make this work.

- check defaults of hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml
- tried the following

> hadoop namenode -format
>
> hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 2g /
>
> hdfs dfsadmin -report         #still shows the old capacity

*Edit:*
Just want to add that with the existing capacity, my name node comes up in safe mode.  So I can't do operations like -format, -rm since I can do read only operations.  I am okay with loosing all data, I just want to shrink an existing HDFS volume.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the disk / space quota is not displayed with -report command. The result just shows how much disk space is available to the hdfs filesystem from the operating systems limitations (of all nodes together).

I'm using hadoop 2.3.0.

Try to do the following on your hadoop box :

```
hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 200g /
```

And afterwards you can get the quota of / by using

```
hdfs dfs -count -q /
9223372036854775807 9223372036854775791    214748364800    214687352772           11            5           30506298 /
```

If you clear the quota using

```
hdfs dfsadmin -clrSpaceQuota /
```

You will get again no limitation (infinite) for disk space:

```
hdfs dfs -count -q /
9223372036854775807 9223372036854775791            none             inf           11            5           30506298 /
```

Maybe this is what you wanted to see!?

Regards

Martin

Comment: Thanks martin, I will try this but do you know if this will solve NameNode starting in safe mode?  I will update the question with clarification.

Comment: Did you try hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

Answer (score 0):

while running -setQuota command check for any of the following

user is not an administrator, or
the directory does not exist or is a file, or
the directory would immediately exceed the new quota.

if all of above are fine then

does the value of your hadoop.tmp.dir is '/' ???